# Can't a durable subscription consumer consume more than 1 message at the same time?

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

Spring Message Listener Container doc says:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html#setDurableSubscriptionName%28java.lang.String%29

> The durable subscription name needs to be unique within this client's
>   JMS client id. Default is the class name of the specified message
>   listener. Note: Only 1 concurrent consumer (which is the default of
>   this message listener container) is allowed for each durable
>   subscription.

I thought, we can handle concurrent messages at the same time. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the documentation is correct. At any point of time there can be only one consumer receiving messages for a durable subscription. All durable subscriptions are identified by a unique id. If one consumer is already receiving messages using an id, another attempt create a consumer with the same id for that durable subscription will fail.

Comment: What is the recommended solution if you want to be able to spin up multiple concurrent consumers for a durable queue? What are the appropriate alternatives?

Comment: Create a separate connection for each consumer and set a unique client id. This allow you to create concurrent consumers for the same topic.

Comment: @BennyMcBenBen : "durable queue" ? I think you mean "durable topic" as queues are always durable. A suggestion for your problem is to have one consumer on the topic pulling out the messages and placing them on a queue with concurrent consumers. This way achieve both durability of subscription (on the topic) and concurrent processing.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before and our log was full of warnings complain about client id is already in use.

Virtual Topic is an option for ActiveMQ: the idea is similar to what @brainOverflow described, it's a combination of topic and queues. The producer sends the message to a topic which is subscribed by queues and each queue receives a copy of the message.

http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html